# Fetch custom size Facebook profile picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to retrieve a Facebook user's profile picture, but at a custom size (e.g.: 40px x 40px). Is this possible, or only the default values (normal, square, small and large) are fetchable?

Comment: FYI: I updated my answer per some new features Facebook has built in recently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<strike>Only those three values are valid from the API. For a 40x40 image though, you can easily resize the 50x50 (`square`) image.</strike>

<strike>Per [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/22/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/) it's now possible to get custom profile picture sizes:</strike>

The blog post was deleted, but it's still possible to get a custom profile picture size using the following parameters:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<ID>/picture?width=<width>&height=<height>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought it would be a built-in solution in the Facebook Graph API.

Comment: is it even possible to work with percentage? example, i don't want to specify a width or a height, but I would like a picture that's 120% of the original. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Only normal, square, small, and large are available, but if you are putting them on a website you can put it into a fixed size div to clip it, or you can download the image programmatically and re-size it yourself.

Comment: I hoped that I can fetch images at whatever size I want. OK, so then I'll try to resize it myself. Thanks for your answer. Oh, and by the way, why have you deleted the 'Thank you!' part from my original message? :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't know that. Won't happen :)